# Removing assembly references sometimes removes imported namespaces

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

How come removing a reference to an assembly (project properties > References) sometimes removes any associated namespaces from the "Imported Namespaces" list and sometimes does not?

I have a single assembly that I relocated on my dev machine and it's referenced by multiple other projects.  I've observed the above-mentioned behavior as I go through each project to fix the reference.

Answer (score 0):

As I guessed in my comment, it appears that it removes the namespace from the "Imported Namespaces" list when the last assembly with any types within that namespace is removed from the project.

To reproduce this, in a new solution - create 3 VB class library projects called `A`, `B` and `C`. In `A` and `B`, change the root namespace to `Flopsy` and rename both `Class1` classes to the same name as their projects (so `A` contains `Flopsy.A` and `B` contains `Flopsy.B`).

Add both `A` and `B` as references to `C` and make `Flopsy` an imported namespace. If you then remove `A` as a reference, the import remains in place. But when you remove the `B` reference also, the import is removed.

You can then repeat the above but remove `B` first and then `A`, and again, the import is removed when the second reference is removed.

So if you're getting different behaviour in different projects, it because of what *other* references those projects also have (and possibly what namespace their own types belong to)

Comment: It's not as complicated as that.  It's only one namespace which is used only by one assembly: the referenced assembly.  This is the case in every project.  Sometimes removing that assembly from a project removes the imported namespace, and other times it does not.